# AWS CDK - How to properly share a generic app/stack across different projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Currently I have a generic CF template that is shared across multiple projects/AWS accounts. It uses CFN parameters so individual projects can enable/disable features as needed.

I am looking to convert this to CDK but I am unsure of how to do this properly.

I have tried the following so far:

Convert the CFN Parameters to context variables - so we can have the projects parameters available at synth time to enable/disable features. I think this will work but context variables don't seem suited for this use-case, from the CDK documentation they cache all sorts of data to do with the AWS account. Because of this I believe I would need to clear the context cache every time I used it, which seems like it would break this:

> The project file cdk.context.json is where the AWS CDK caches context values retrieved from your AWS account. This practice avoids unexpected changes to your deployments when, for example, a new Amazon Linux AMI is released, changing your Auto Scaling group.

The fact that CDK is going to cache account specific values makes me think if a generic stack like this is even possible. Will I need to create a CDK app for each project and then reuse the stack for each app?

How do I structure a generic stack that is reusable across projects/AWS accounts?

Comment: You can use environment variables.

Comment: Will this not lead to the same issue with the context cache containing account specific data?

I.e `ENV=1 cdk synth`, context cache now contains data for that AWS account. In order to run it with a different AWS account I would need to clear the cache, which will have the possibly to cause the issues mentioned in the quoted text of my original post?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar (i.e. share a generic CDK app across unrelated projects). I think creating a npm/pip package will work. It's not a native solution, but it provides full control and lets you distribute as needed.

Answer (score 0):

CDK is support for [CfnParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/parameters.html) as well. You can use the parameters same way as you are doing now with CFN template.

You can create parameter like below and use it wherever you want to use.

```
const uploadBucketName = new CfnParameter(this, "uploadBucketName", {
  type: "String",
  description: "The name of the Amazon S3 bucket where uploaded files will be stored."});

const bucket = new Bucket(this, "myBucket", 
  { bucketName: uploadBucketName.valueAsString});
```

To deploy you can pass the parameters.

```
cdk deploy MyStack --parameters uploadBucketName=UploadBucket
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ssm parameter store to share parameters from one stack to another:

One stack writes the parameter

```
import * as ssm from '@aws-cdk/aws-ssm';
new ssm.StringParameter(this, 'MyParameter', {
  parameterName: '/myPrefix/myS3BucketArn',
  stringValue: s3Bucket.bucketArn
});
```

The other stack reads it

```
const s3BucketArn = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this, '/myPrefix/myS3BucketArn');
```